# Volume control via media keys in xubuntu

Tags: sound, shortcut-keys

I noticed that the volume control when I use xubuntu is not really working properly.

I can see, that xubuntu is recognizing that it should do something and displays a small image indicating volume up/down or mute. But, it is not affecting the sound I hear for instance while using youtube.

When I open my PulseAudio I see in Output Devices Tab two devices: Built in Audio Digital Stereo and Built-in Analog Stereo. The indication for sound volume for the first device actually does react when I press the media keys for volume up/down. But this should be the second device that should be controlled by my media keys. So the question is, how do I change the device controlled by media keys?

Also, I noticed, that under Ubuntu the media keys work fine, and it is possible to control volume with them..

Comment: Turn off the Output you don't want.

Comment: Yes, how do I do that though?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same trouble. The advice on this page fixed it for me:

http://ulno.net/2011/04/16/mixer-control-with-multimedia-keys-und-multiple-soundcards-in-xfce4-on-debian-or-ubuntu/

In short:
Settings -> Settings Editor
Find the section `xfce4-mixer`.
Set the value of property `active-card` to the same as the value of `sound-card`.